# Model the sequence $10,20,\dots,100,200,\dots,1000,2000,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am developing  a function in Java to calculate/predict the future age of a person on a certain date. For this I am choosing a constraint of $10$. So I am adding $10$ years from the start date and predicting so each time $10$ keeps adding up , it becomes $10$ then $20$ then $30$ then $40$ (on a certain date in future in all the cases) but when I reach the figure $100$ I don't want to add $10$ and instead add $100$ then it becomes $100+100 = 200$, then $300, 400$ etc. Now when this reaches $1000$ I want to add a thousand so it becomes $2000$ then $3000$ etc now again the process continues. Is there any Mathematical Progression such that I can implement the same?

Comment: You could define it recursively as $a_0 = 10$, and $a_n = a_{n-1} + 10^{\lfloor\log_{10} a_{n-1}\rfloor}$; I make no claims that I write good code or that it is computationally efficient.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the above? An example with original numbers?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, I thought you were trying to produce a formula which would yield the sequence $10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,\ldots,900,1000,2000,\ldots$. That is precisely what my recursion yields.

Comment: Yes exactly I meant the same. Let me try this now. Also is this a general formula?

Comment: Could you please explain this formula using a real number?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I have clearly exhibited a formula for the desired sequence. What do you mean "explain this using a real number?" and "is this a general formula?"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing code to do this, you can convert each number to a string, find the length of the string using $$L(a_k) = \mbox{ String.valueOf(} a_k \mbox{).length()}$$ and then add $10^{L-1}$.  So,

> $$a_0 = 0$$ and $$ a_n = a_{n-1} + 10^{L(a_{n-1})-1} $$

I will demonstrate it for 20, 90, 100, 900 and 1000:
$$ a_0 = 10 $$
$$ a_1 = a_0 + 10^{L(a_0)-1} = 10 + 10^{1} = 20$$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ a_k = 90$$
$$ a_{k+1} = a_k + 10^{L(a_k)-1} = 90 + 10^{1} = 100$$
$$ a_{k+2} = a_{k+1} + 10^{L(a_{k+1})-1} = 100 + 10^{2} = 200$$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ a_n = 900$$
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n + 10^{L(a_n)-1} = 900 + 10^{2} = 1000$$
$$ a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 10^{L(a_{n+1})-1} = 1000 + 10^{3} = 2000$$
$$ \vdots $$

Answer (score 0):

For the first 100 years, do you want as follows?

$x$ is the present age of a person.
$100-x=y$

$\Large x+\lceil \frac{y}{10} \rceil\times 10$

If $x=10$, then $10+\lceil \frac{90}{10} \rceil\times 10=100$

If $x=55$, then $55+\lceil \frac{45}{10} \rceil\times 10=105$

Comment: What happens after 1000? Also I am not concerned for numbers like 105 as I explained.